# Words spelled the same way they are pronounced

Tags: homophones, homonyms, heteronyms

Is there a term for words that are spelled the same way they are pronounced? If so, is there a list of them somewhere?

For example, I have thought of:

- "a" spelled A pronounced "A"
- "I" spelled I pronounced "I"
- "ok" spelled O-K pronounced "O"-"K"
- "Io" (Jupiter's moon) spelled I-O pronounced "I"-"O"

More explicitly, words whose spelling is pronounced the same as how the word itself is pronounced.

Comment: To those downvoting, could you please explain how I could improve my question? It seems like there's an easy answer, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Welcome new user, it's completely unsuitable for this site: ask on the excellent English Learner's site.

Comment: @Fattie, I'm a native English speaker, but if you think it's more suitable there, I can ask. I thought this fell more into the homonym / homophone category of questions. It seemed too nuanced for English learners.

Comment: Ryan - actually fair enough - you're right. Happy new year!

Comment: I once asked if there's a term for words which were coined due to looking like their physical typographical representation (such as the new word "uwu") - so I can't complain :)

Comment: I apologize for the behavior of some of my colleagues. I've upvoted to compensate.

Comment: In all fairness, I must hasten to add that questions should be posted only in the form of questions. I'm well aware that this rule hasn't been followed here for years. That said, the opening sentence of your OP would do nicely.

Comment: As for your actual question, no, I don't think there's a term for words that are phonetically spelled. Oh, and Io was an Argive princess before she was a moon.

Comment: @Ricky, thank you. Do you know if there may be a list somewhere for these? I've only thought of these few and I'm afraid the list may be short but surely there must be a few more.

Comment: @ryan: No clue. I'm with you in that the list must be quite short. Which is quite normal. There were attempts to create a phonetic alphabet for the English language. Most of them date back to more than a century ago. They all failed. Phonetic alphabets don't exist. We're stuck with this Greco-Roman nonsense forever. Which is fine by me. There's something repulsively algebraic about the idea. Math and harmony don't mix.

Comment: A, I , O and K are simply names of letters; I'd hardly classify them as words whose spelling was of any significance.

Comment: @KateBunting, that's the point. If they weren't the names of the letters then they wouldn't follow this rule. The significance is exactly what's posed in my question. :P

Comment: @KateBunting, maybe if there's a list of letters whose name is pronounced the same as one of their pronunciations, then that would be a start because words in this category would have to be made up of letters from that list (I think).

Comment: Well, you could argue that the only one that isn't is W! (and H is sometimes written 'aitch'.)

Comment: @KateBunting I think the question is about their use as words independently of being the names of letters, e.g. `I` is a pronoun and `A` is an article. `W` is not a word.

Comment: And what of the (departed) Zed, Kat?

Comment: Point of order: although rendering "okay" as a "ok," with no punctuation, is common casual usage, I'm not sure it should qualify as a word per se. (Is there a word for the curious case of "okay," which [apparently](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ok) started life as an abbreviation for an intentional misspelling and then was reverse-engineered into a phonetic long-form representation of the sound of the two letters?)

Comment: I also wonder: is there a term for words that can be phonetically represented by the pronunciation of the names of individual letters (like when I found it amusingly ironic that the iPhone XS, named aloud, bespoke "excess")?...

Comment: Since English spelling doesn't represent pronunciation, there can't be any words that are spelled as they are pronounced.

Comment: @JohnLawler are there any languages that do function that way?

Comment: No. There are very few languages with orthographies that don't represent their pronunciation. Like the spelling bee, this is an English idiosyncracy.

Comment: How about "weird"?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase *phonemic orthography* seems to describes spelling phonetically<sup>1</sup>

[phonemic](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/phonemic)

> of or relating to the phoneme(smallest unit of sound which is significant in a language)

[orthography](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/orthography)

> a writing system

> spelling considered to be correct

> the principles underlying spelling

Can't find a list of words spelled the same way they are pronounced.

<sup><sup>1</sup> https://www.dictionary.com/e/phonetic-spelling/ and https://qr.ae/pGJxel</sup>

Comment: Good point that, in a language that employs phonemic orthography, assuming that each phoneme's "name" is the same as its "sound," then every word would meet the OP's description. But modern English (the topic of this SE and assumed context of the question) does not.

Answer (score -1):

Onomatopoeia. Onomatopoeic.
Actually it means the worded is spelled to imitate the actual sound made by the word. eg Shatter.

Comment: None of the examples are onomatopoeias.